# How to display 2 lists views in a page horizontally

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have 2 list views that have 1 column.  I want to display both views (a total of 2 columns) side by side in a page.  Is that possible ?  I do not have SP designer. Thus, I have a Marketing Empl list that has a 1 column which is a px of the empl and I have another list called "HR list" again with 1 column that has the employees px.  The page should display as the below

Marketing Empl PX  HR Empl PX

I suppose I could create 2 columns in 1 list, but then thats de-normalizing the data,,,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify what kind of page you are using. You could use a web part page with two web part zones side by side. Or on a wiki page you can insert a table with two columns and one row and place a list view into each cell. Remove the table borders to make it invisible.

Comment: Im using a regular page...I am selecting "Add Page"..then I am adding my web parts... I notice when I go into edit a web part the zone is greyed out and all the webparts appear to say Zone2...Hope this helps provide some more detail...

Comment: Select a different web part page layout. Some have zones side by side, some don't.